# Trying to run project from github of yarn framework but unable to run even after installing npm and all dependency

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

internal/modules/c j s/loader.js:968 throw err; ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\app-master\run' [90m at

Function. Module._ resolve Filename (internal/modules/c j s/loader.js:965:15)[39m [90m at Function .Module. _load (internal/modules/c j s/loader.js:841:27)[39m [90m at Function .execute User Entry Point [as run Main] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m [90m at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m { code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m, require Stack: []OT_FOUND'[39m,
requireStack: []

Answer (score 0):

Look at your all imported modules.
It seems you didn't import them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

seeems you dont have made .env file we put it in gitignore so most of the time we miss it create a .env file and set all variable  and then try to run

Tihis must help you if you are running project from github or someone else i did the same mistake last time even after downloading all moudle i was unable

still have problem please revert it